# Can this one used with JSF1.2 together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I have an old application which use JSF 1.2. The file upload component is `rich:fileUpload`. The rich fileupload needs Flash Player support, but the Flash Player will discontinue by end of 2020. I change to tomahawk to handle the file upload, but my boss ask for better solution like jQuery or so.

I take a quick look about this framework, but I don't have an idea about how to use this framework with my old JSF 1.2 application together? Please give me some tips or hints? Thank you in advance.

Comment: "this one" or "the file upload component is" or "this framework" or.... is all not clear... Please improve your question

Comment: @Kukeltje: I guess he thought that jQuery itself is a "framework" ..

Comment: Vincent, better is to recommend your boss to focus on migrating from JSF 1.2 to current latest available (2.3) as soon as possible. RichFaces was already end of life in 2016 and nowadays there's PrimeFaces available as a jQuery based JSF component library. It also has a file upload component https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml

Comment: @BalusC: I think so, but I wanted OP to check out his own question since it was badly formatted initially (Jasper de Vries actually corrected it where I left it intentionally 'wrong'. I agree with your comment though.